# makefile process multiple files and output converted files with similar names

Tags: makefile, latex

Say i have the following files:

```
makefile
file1_ENG.yaml
file2_NL.yaml
template.tex
```

I would like to have the `makefile` output **pdf** files from all the **yaml** files.

So in this case, 2 pdf's with the **same names**, `file1_ENG.pdf` & `file2_NL.pdf`.

Currently I have:

```
TEX = pandoc
src = template.tex $(wildcard *.yml)
FLAGS = --latex-engine=xelatex

file1_ENG.pdf : $(src)
    $(TEX) $(filter-out $<,$^ ) --verbose -o $@ --template=$< $(FLAGS)

.PHONY: clean
clean :
    rm file1_ENG.pdf
```

dont know if the wildcard thing is working.. also how to get the names of the imported files and use these as output filenames?

Comment: Does it matter whether you build all of the pdf files with one call to pandoc, or call pandoc once for each of them?

Comment: @Beta No it can be separate :) but they yml files can be named whatever and the pdf file name should reflect it;)

Comment: I imagine a forloop of somesort

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First get the wildcard working:

```
src := $(wildcard *.yml)
$(info $(src)) # you can remove this once you see the wildcard works
```

Then construct a list of the desired pdf files:

```
TARGETS := $(patsubst %.yaml,%.pdf,$(src))
```

Then write a [static pattern rule](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Static-Pattern) to build one from the other:

```
TEX = pandoc
FLAGS = --latex-engine=xelatex
TEMPLATE := template.tex

$(TARGETS): %.pdf : %.yaml $(TEMPLATE)
    $(TEX) $< --verbose -o $@ --template=$(TEMPLATE) $(FLAGS)
```

And a `clean` rule:

```
.PHONY: clean
clean :
    rm *.pdf
```

And an `all` rule, which goes first:

```
all: $(TARGETS)
```

Comment: you sir are a boss! ;)

Comment: does it now loop over all yml files? :)

Comment: mmh i would like the output pdf's to get in a a folder. So i put `-o folder/$@` in. However it now seems the clean doesnt work even though i adjusted it to `folder/*.pdf` ... if you made no changes, it should say *...pdf is up to date*

Comment: last thing... how would i go about generating a random hash folder name for each yml file converted into pdf file inside the folder? so it would become folder/folderhash121234123123123/*.pdf

Comment: @strages: If you change the thing being built (from `foo.pdf` to `folder/foo.pdf`), and don't change the target accordingly, Make will think it's still building `foo.pdf` and get confused. And if you want Make to construct a *random* path for the things it builds, the rules get tricky. I'll have to give it some thought...

Comment: ha oke :) most important is to know how to fix the output to another folder.. the random foldername would be an extension

Comment: @strages: that part isn't hard to find on SO, it's been asked and answered many times.

Comment: fixed it with `$(BUILDDIR)/` and `BUILDDIR = public` :D